# Allow users to view others contents with autocomplete Entity Reference field

Tags: hooks, users, nodes, entities

I'm trying to build a content type where any user can select an entity reference value through an **autocompleted Entity Reference field**.

Using this field works as an admin. I'm able to see the referenced contents. But when I try as a logged in lambda user, I **can't view the content created by other users**.

The field is in the content type "**Invoice**" and has to allow users to select a contact name (content type "**Contact**").

I think it's a matter of access rights on this specific content type. So far, I've tryed creating a module with a `hook_node_access` function :

```
function contact_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;

  if (in_array($type, node_permissions_get_configured_types())) {
    if ($op == 'view' && user_access('view ' . $type . ' content', $account)) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }
  }

}
```

It still doesn't allow users to see and select other's people contacts.

Comment: If you can't see other peoples content, do you have any content access related modules installed, or are the nodes from other users unpublished?

Comment: Oh damn you're right... This was the problem that I didn't notice before. Thanks, you can post the answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if a user cannot see another user's content then it is either because there is a content access module installed that is restricting access or the content is unpublished.

By default in Drupal you cannot see unpublished content unless you created it or you are an administrator with access to all content.